# linking error: __thiscall function symbol not found but __cdecl function symbol is defined

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, cmake

I'm trying to compile with Visual Studio 2012 a test program which should link against the test.lib file given to me by a colleague.

The compilation stops at the linking step with the error LNK2019. The missing symbol is:

```
public: virtual __thiscall abc::Test::~Test(void)
```

Using the utility `dumpbin`, I found that inside test.lib the following symbol is defined:

```
public: virtual __cdecl abc::Test::~Test(void)
```

What is the difference between these two functions? How can I fix this compilation problem? Am I missing some compilation flags?

Comment: did you define the destructor?

Comment: You are more than likely compiling your test program with differing compiler options than what your colleague compiled his library with.  A difference in calling convention leads me to believe this.

Comment: @Raindrop7: the destructor is defined

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: do you know which flags I should check?

Comment: It isn't only the compiler options.  Any preprocessor symbols that may turn on / off the particular calling convention can also effect what is going on.  You need to coordinate with your colleague and compare, very carefully how he / she is building the library, and how you're building your application code.  A static library is nothing more than object code packaged up in a single file.  However that object code has to be basically the same object code generated as if you had taken one of the library's source files and built it yourself in your application.  Obviously this is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

You are not missing flags.

[Calling convention modifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k2b2ssfy.aspx), such as `__thiscall` and `__cdecl`, modify the function's name internally. Thus, `__thiscall abc::Test::~Test(void)` is *not* the same function as `__cdecl abc::Test::~Test(void)`. To fix this, change `__thiscall` to `__cdecl`.

IIRC, `__cdecl` is the default calling convention for MSVC (Visual Studio's compiler), so if your colleague didn't specify anything special, dumpbin will describe the function as having a `__cdecl` calling convention.

**Explanation:**

Unlike in C, the internal name of C++ functions, methods and objects are *not* the same as those in your source files. This is called [name mangling](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/56h2zst2.aspx#FormatC) (sometimes called *name decoration*). Name mangling allows functions to be overloaded, that is, to have several functions that differ only by their argument type, as well as class/namespace membership, etc.

Assume I have the following C program :

```
// Foo.c
#include <stdio.h>

void myPrint(void) {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
}

void myPrint(const char* str) {
    printf(str);
}

int main() {
    myPrint();
    myPrint("Hello, World!\n");
}
```

If you try to compile it as C code:

```
$ gcc -o Foo Foo.c
Foo.c:7:6: error: redefinition of ‘myPrint’
```

But if you try to compile this as C++:

```
$ g++ -o Foo Foo.c
```

It compiles.

If you try to view the assembly with `g++ -o Foo.s Foo.cpp -S -Os`, you will see that the `void myPrint(void);` function's mangled name is `_Z7myPrintv` (the final `v` stands for `void`), while the `void myPrint(const char*);` function's mangled name is `_Z7myPrintPKc` (`PKc` : Pointer to a Konstant Char).

By the way, the mangled name of a function depends on the compiler you are using. With MSVC (Visual Studio's compiler), `void myPrint(const char*);` has the following mangled name : `?myPrint@@YAXPBD@Z`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. The problem I have now is that I don't know how to change __thiscall to __cdecl. I looked at the code and haven't found anything which suggests the compilation with __thiscall or __cdecl.

Comment: Don't just look at the code. Look at the code generation options.  Maybe the library was compiled with differing optimization settings or other setting.  You need to load both your project and the library project in Visual Studio, and ensure all code generation related settings are the same.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - In the original post I didn't mention I use CMake with the Visual Studio 11 generator. I just made an experiment with Scons and it compiled (I carefully added all the defines and flags added automatically by CMake) !  But since the flags and defines are the same what else could it be? I'm running both the compilations from the same standard prompt.

Comment: I finally managed to compile also with CMake.  Instead of using the CMake generator "Visual Studio 11" I used the generator "Visual Studio 11 Win64"  and everything was ok. Is there a difference on how Visual Studio handles `__thiscall` and `__cdecl` when using
`C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/VC/bin/cl.exe`
or 
`C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0/VC/bin/x86_amd64/cl.exe`
?